# ORDER BY x > 10 in PHP

Tags: php, sql

How can I call ORDER BY recommend > 10 DESC?

this code works but brings me results with recommend 1 or > but I need recomment 10 or >. How can I write?

```
feedContent = SELECT (
            "*, count(*) AS recommend", 
            "post", 
            "$INNER_USER 
            INNER JOIN post_type ON post_id = type_post_id 
            WHERE post_status = 1 AND type_post = 'recommend' $category
            GROUP BY post_id 
            ORDER BY recommend DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Illegal use of GROUP BY ... you cannot select fields which are not part of the group by.. Apart from that: `SELECT recommend, count(*) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY recommend HAVING count(*) > 10` (this will only list groups of "recommend" with mire than 10 records)

Comment: You can use `HAVING recommend >= 10` after your `GROUP BY`

Comment: THANKSSSS works 

   GROUP BY post_id HAVING recommend > 10 ORDER BY recommend DESC 

Do I need to close this question???

Comment: @Bruno why not post your solution as an Answer? Take the [tour] to ensure you know how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was.

Thank you so much guys

```
$feedContent = SELECT (
            "*, count(*) AS recommend", 
            "post", 
            "
            INNER JOIN post_type ON post_id = type_post_id 
            WHERE post_status = 1 AND type_post = 'recommend' 
            GROUP BY post_id HAVING recommend > 2
            ORDER BY recommend DESC LIMIT X");
```